# Worklight QA Send mail

Tags: smtp, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

I'm using Worklight QA and I got an error trying to send mails using SendGrid.
The error was on the Send activation link for the user.

This is part of the error on `celeryd.log`

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: UNKNOWN STATUS CODE
[2014-09-29 13:29:55,549: WARNING/Worker-3] Unable to reach Sentry log server: HTTP 
                          Error 429: UNKNOWN STATUS CODE (url: https://app.getsentry.
                          com/api/13389/store/, body: Creation of this event was
                          denied due to rate limiting.)
[2014-09-29 13:29:55,555: ERROR/MainProcess] Failed to submit message: u'error:
                          [Errno 111] Connection refused'
[2014-09-29 13:29:55,556: WARNING/Worker-3] Failed to submit message: u'error:
                          [Errno 111] Connection refused'
[2014-09-29 13:29:55,558: ERROR/MainProcess] Task notifications.email.ActivationEmail
                          [88c97bed-812a-427f-98a1-9bc77ff38876] raised exception:
                          error(111, 'Connection refused')
```

I've configured `local_settings.py` with the SendGrid information, the SendGrid account is provisioned and ready to send mails.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '******'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

I've also tried to disable iptables on the server thinking on local firewall issue, but It was getting the same error.

I don't know if this rate limiting error from Sentry has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly be some kind of SMTP integration issue on your end. Not sure Sentry has anything to do with it.

Suggest changing `EMAIL_USE_TLS` to True and see if that works. It is possible that SendGrid is enforcing that.